# Create a list of objects in plsql - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a list of objects in PL/SQL - postgres and return it as table to user.

Here is the scenario. I have two table called

```
create table ProcessDetails(
    processName varchar,
    processstartdate timestamp,
    processenddate timestamp);

create table processSLA(
    processName varchar,
    sla numeric);
```

Now I need to loop over all the records in processDetails table and check which records for each activity type has breached sla, within sla and those that are more 80% of sla.

I would need help in understanding how to loop over records and create a collection in which for each processtype I have details required.

```
sample data from processdetails table

    ProcessName  processstartdate             processenddate   
----------------------------------------------------- 
    "Create"    "2018-12-24 13:11:05.122694"    null
    "Delete"    "2018-12-24 12:12:24.269266"    null
    "Delete"    "2018-12-23 13:12:31.89164"     null
    "Create"    "2018-12-22 13:12:37.505486"    null

    processSLA
       ProcessName  sla(in hrs) 
    ---------------------------------
       Create       1
       Delete       10
```

And the output will look something like this

```
ProcessName  WithinSLA(Count)  BreachedSLA(Count) Exceeded80%SLA(Count)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Create                 1                1              3
Delete                 1                2              1
```

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL or Oracle?

Comment: I am using postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each SLA, you can look up all corresponding process details with a `join`.  The link between two joined tables specified in a join condition.  For your example, `using (processName)` would work.

To find processes that have exceeded the SLA, say that the allowed end date is smaller than the actual end date:

```
select  processName
,       count(case when det.processstartdate + interval '1 hour' * sla.hours >=
            coalesce(det.processenddate, now()) then 1 end) as InSLA
,       count(case when det.processstartdate + interval '1 hour' * sla.hours <
            coalesce(det.processenddate, now()) then 1 end) as BreachedSLA
,       count(case when det.processstartdate + interval '1 hour' * 0.8 * sla.hours <
            coalesce(det.processenddate, now()) then 1 end) as 80PercentSLA
from    processSLA sla
left join
        ProcessDetails det
using   (processName)
group by
        processName
```

Comment: I need data something like this..


ProcessName  WithinSLA(Count)  BreachedSLA(Count) Exceeded80%SLA(Count)

Create                 1                             1                                     3

Comment: You can `group by` process name, and then count the number of rows within or without the SLA

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables and use conditional aggregation based on the calculation of the difference between the timestamps.

Something like that:

```
SELECT count(CASE
               WHEN extract(EPOCH FROM pd.processenddate - pd.processstartdate) / 3600 < ps.sla * .8 THEN
                1
             END) "less than 80%",
       count(CASE
               WHEN extract(EPOCH FROM pd.processenddate - pd.processstartdate) / 3600 >= ps.sla * .8
                    AND extract(EPOCH FROM pd.processenddate - pd.processstartdate) / 3600 <= ps.sla THEN
                1
             END) "80% to 100%",
       count(CASE
               WHEN extract(EPOCH FROM pd.processenddate - pd.processstartdate) / 3600 > ps.sla THEN
                1
             END) "more than 100%"                
       FROM processdetails pd
            INNER JOIN processsla ps
                       ON ps.processname = pd.processname;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need other two columns in the answer. I need those within SLA, exceeded SLA too along with 80% of the sla.. how to I get those.. I need the count of records, not the records it self.

Comment: @PradeepSreeram: If you want them all, simply remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I will not get the count. I will get records. What I need to count of each type of records... those within sla , breaded and nearing 80% for each process type. The above query will return multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. processend will be null sometimes. if processenddate is null it means the process is still pending.. how to handle that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!